# Need help writing a dynamic method that gives user a different prompt when the method is called with a different parameter every time

Tags: java, arrays, string, dynamic

Im trying to write a method that works around user choices (ex. queryChoicesMethod). There are 4 choices that the user can pick, and at the end of it all, all 4 choices have to be in a String[] in some order. Say you have choices a, b, c, and d. You ask the user to pick the first choice, and the static method will return the first choice as a string. The answer will then get put into the array at [0] in the main method. When I call the queryChoicesMethod again, this time it should say something like, "please select a second choice ..." and it will list the other choices the user hasn't already picked yet (ex. Say the user picked "a" the first time around, at the call during the second time, it should print something like "please pick options b, c, or d"). The answer will then go into the String[] at [1]. During the third call, it should ask the user the to pick any one of the two remaining options (ex. if user picked "b" the second time, method should print "please pick options c or d" during the third call). Answer will go into String[] at [2]. The last remaining option would get put into the array without calling the method again, because you dont have to ask the user to put in the last option (its already decided that the last option goes into the array at [3] during this stage because its the only option left).

I've tried to do everything I can, but have failed. This is an assignment that I cant figure out

The method that I must use is as follows:

public static String queryChoices(String[] choices) {}

Thanks for any help

Comment: "I've tried to do everything I can, but have failed."  Show what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a static variable and increment in your method. Map the variable values with words like first, second in order to use in your print statement.
Use a boolean array for your choices to help you know whether it is taken or not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class HelloWorld{
 public static int i=0;
 public static String num[]={"first","second","third","fourth"};
 public static boolean taken[]={false,false,false,false};
 static String[] choicelist={"","","",""};
 public static String queryChoices(String[] choices){
    HelloWorld h=new HelloWorld();
    int l;    
    String ch;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    if(i<3){
        System.out.println("enter your "+num[i]+" choice:\n The choices are");
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            if(!taken[j])
                System.out.println(j+". "+choices[j]);
        }    
        int n=s.nextInt();
        taken[n]=true;
        h.choicelist[i]=choices[n];
        ch=choices[n];
        i++;
    }else{
        for(l=0;l<4;l++){
            if(!taken[l])
            break;
        }
        h.choicelist[3]=choices[l];
        ch=choices[l];
    }
   return ch; 

 }
 public static void main(String []args){
    String[] choices={"a","b","c","d"};

    String choice=queryChoices(choices);
    System.out.println("your choice is: "+ choice);
    System.out.println("your choice is: "+ choicelist[0]);

 }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't have to return the whole array. It actually only needs to return the answer that the user gives every time the method is called (that may sounds inefficient, but that is the assignment).